# mark-sexp (Wrong number of arguments)

Tags: debugging, mark, sexp

```
((foo(bar))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 (baz))
```

If point is on `bar` and I do `M-x mark-sexp`, I get this error:

```
Wrong number of arguments: (lambda nil "Activate the mark." (if (mark t) (progn (setq mark-active t) (if transient-mark-mode nil (setq transient-mark-mode (quote lambda))) (if (and select-active-regions (display-selections-p)) (progn (x-\
set-selection (quote PRIMARY) (current-buffer))))))), 1
```

```
Enabled minor modes: Async-Bytecomp-Package Auto-Composition                                                                                                                                                                                  
Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption Auto-Revert Column-Number Dap                                                                                                                                                                                
Dap-Auto-Configure Dap-Tooltip Dap-Ui Dap-Ui-Controls                                                                                                                                                                                         
Dap-Ui-Many-Windows Diff-Auto-Refine Display-Time Electric-Indent                                                                                                                                                                             
Electric-Pair File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Edit-Server-Edit                                                                                                                                                                              
Global-Eldoc Global-Font-Lock Global-Git-Commit Global-Magit-File                                                                                                                                                                             
Google-This Ido-Everywhere Iswitchb Jabber-Activity Line-Number                                                                                                                                                                               
Magit-Auto-Revert Magit-File Mouse-Wheel Override-Global                                                                                                                                                                                      
Shell-Dirtrack Show-Paren Tool-Bar Tooltip Transient-Mark                                                                                                                                                                                     
Treemacs-Filewatch Treemacs-Follow Treemacs-Fringe-Indicator                                                                                                                                                                                  
Treemacs-Git Which-Key Xclip
```

Comment: Probably a bug with the version you are using: I don't see it in GNU Emacs 28.0.50 (build 3, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.13, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2020-08-31.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that with other any version of Emacs, from 20 through 26.3.

Are you actually in `emacs-lisp-mode` or `lisp-mode`?  (You probably should be.)

Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)?  If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

If you see the same thing without your init file, please provide a complete, step-by-step recipe to reproduce it, starting from `emacs -Q`.

Comment: It works if I start up in emacs -Q. I'll update the question with minor modes enabled

Comment: Please bisect your init file to find the culprit (as opposed to expecting reviewers here to check all the minor modes you show, to see which might introduce the problem). You can use command `comment-region` to comment a region of your init file (with `C-u` it uncomments). Comment out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16,... till you find the culprit.